# Calculating Averages in Ruby Name Error

Tags: ruby

I'm getting this:

```
 NameError: undefined local variable or method `sentence_count' for main:Object
```

when I type this:

```
 puts "#{sentence_count / paragraph_count} sentences per paragraph (average)"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't Error self-explanatory.

Comment: For you guys just that just edit & vote things down. With no help... You guys are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NameError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/NameError.html) raises when you try to use an undefined name.  Take a moment to read & understand that the error is telling you `sentence_count` is undefined.